# How can you determine where two polynomials cross and are tangent to each other, just by factorising the difference?

Tags: functions, polynomials, graphing-functions

My textbook asked me to factorise the difference between P(x) and Q(x) and describe the intersection.
I'm having trouble understanding:

1. Why doing this would allow me to describe the intersection
2. And how to describe the intersection

Question from my textbook:
$P(x) = x^4 + 4x^3 − x + 5$
$Q(x) = x^3 − 3x^2 − 2x + 5$

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When $P(x)=Q(x)$, what does $P(x)-Q(x)$ equal?

Comment: You mention "tangent" in the title, but not in the post. Know that polynomials intersecting does not necessarily mean that they are tangent at the point of intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Points of intersection are when $P(x) = Q(x) \iff P(x) - Q(x) = 0$ this is, i think, the difference you are looking for.

Hope this helps.